# My power supply suddenly does not deliver enough power to GPU

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, gpu

My computer was built last year in September and everything had gone well, until now. The PC did not even power on. I tried to clear the CMOS without any luck.

I managed to remove the GPU, and it finally powered on. Everything worked well, as I connect my monitor to the integrated GPU. However, whenever I try to connect my GTX 1070 to my motherboard, my computer won't start. I then started to figure out that the PSU causes the problems.

I have a Cooler Master V650 650W PSU with an ASUS Strix GTX 1070 GPU. So my question is: Do I have to buy a more powerful PSU?

Comment: 650W should be enough. This could be a few things: motherboard broke and your PCIe 16x slot is broke so its causing a short or something, PSU broke and should be able to be repaired under warranty, or GFX card (hope it's not this one) broke and is taking up way too much power for some reason..

Comment: Thanks for the answer man, I'll try to test the GPU and the PSU with my mate's PC :-)

Comment: @varfirstName The computer suddenly worked well with the GFX! I just can't figure out why it sometimes fails.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the GPU, it should be under warranty, given it's the current generation

Comment: Try reseating power cables, particularly the ones to the GPU. (If you haven't already.)

Comment: I found the solution to this problem. I recently bought an Acer Predator 1440p monitor. Besides that, I got two other 1080p monitors. When I managed to connect all the three monitors, the PC won't start for some reason. It kinda does not make sense... 
2 DisplayPort to the PC will kill the entire system, but it worked fine with 1 DP and 1 HDMI.

Answer (score 0):

If your system wasn't powering on at all, your GFX card is probably a little big and was pushing against power button headers if not even a fan started. This happened with my GPU previously, and has taught me to be careful with it. Otherwise, the GFX card might be damaged, in which case you can get it checked out if it's still under warranty.